# Use of joomla methods stops file to work in plugin

Tags: ajax, plugins, joomla

I've created simple ajax voting plugin, it works fine.. till i start to use joomla methods in conf.php file. The file below is conf.php with simple php db query, if i put here for example $dbb = JRequest::getDbo(); it stops working .. or any other joomla methods. I can't get it what is wrong here?

```
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "plugins/system/ratingx/conf.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
```

conf.php:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1) or die;
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "px";
$mysql_password = "px";
$mysql_database = "jum";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");


if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);


mysql_query("update messages set $name=$name+1 where id='$id'");


$result=mysql_query("select up,down from messages where id='$id'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$up_value=$row['up'];
$down_value=$row['down'];
$total=$up_value+$down_value;

$up_per=($up_value*100)/$total;
$down_per=($down_value*100)/$total;
?>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<b>Ratings for this blog</b> ( <?php echo $total; ?> total)
</div>
<table width="700px">

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $up_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="greebar" style="width:<?php echo $up_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $down_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="redbar" style="width:<?php echo $down_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

</table>

<?php

}
```

Comment: woah...ok first of all, what version of Joomla are you using? Second of all, you don't need to manually connect to the database if you keep within the Joomla standards of files and coding, which I recommend you do if you already haven't. You should read the documentation on connecting to a Joomla databse which will help keep the code cleaner and simplified. `$db = &JFactory::getDBO();` is what you should be looking into ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what version of Joomla! you're using but...

The problem is that you're calling a file that exists "outside" the Joomla! framework, just because you've defined `_JEXEC` doesn't mean the framework is loaded.

To be able to use `JRequest` or even `JFactory::getDBO()` you will also need to initialise Joomla!'s front-end app and load the framework/classes required.  Doing that can potentially leave your site with a security issue.

I would suggest you [create a basic component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction) with an appropriate AJAX/RAW controller that your plugin can call through the default Joomla! path (i.e. `index.php`).

If you do want to by pass the Joomla! application then look at the main `index.php` for your version of Joomla to give you a guide has to how to load the applications framework.

*p.s. `JRequest::getDBO()` isn't valid, `getDBO()` is not a method of `JRequest` (any version)*