# Joomla plugin ajax connection, db error

Tags: ajax, plugins, joomla

i'm continuing my plugin development saga..
so i've corrected all mistakes which i made in previuos code -> [Use of joomla methods stops file to work in plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448245/use-of-joomla-methods-stops-file-to-work-in-plugin#comment16744736_12448245)

And now i thought i made everything well, but db query dont work. I have no idea what is wrong here, db query looks good to me

```
<?php
// Set flag that this is a parent file
define('_JEXEC', 1);

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
jimport( 'joomla.database.database' );


$db = JFactory::getDbo();

if(JRequest::getInt('id'))
{

$id = JRequest::getInt('id');
$name = JRequest::getVar('name');

$query = "update #__messages set $name=$name+1 where id='$id'";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query( $query ) or die('blogai');


?>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<b>Ratings for this blog</b> ( <?php echo $total; ?> total)
</div>
<table width="700px">

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $up_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="greebar" style="width:<?php echo $up_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $down_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="redbar" style="width:<?php echo $down_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

</table>

<?php

}
```

Comment: what makes you think that db query is not working ? are you getting any error message.  Try to print $db after $db->query( $query ) to get some more detail about the issue.

Comment: i get output the (or die) "blogai" output. where do i have to put that print $db code. it after query it wont work i think because of output "blogai"

Answer (score 0):

Try this..its working for me

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
chdir("../../");
getcwd();
define('JPATH_BASE', getcwd() );

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once (JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

global $mainframe;

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$db         =  JFactory::getDBO();
```

Comment: check this line in your file `define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..' );`..seems this is problem...give correct DS count....

Comment: can you post your folder path ?